# Открытие любого количества модальных окон по ссылке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго дня!

Нужна помощь. Если кто может, то пожалуйста.
Есть скрипт модального окна. Он открывает одно окно по классу. Как его переделать, чтобы он открывал любое кол-во окон по ссылке `<a href id...`, присвоив персональный `id` каждому окну? А также использовать одну подложку для всех окон. Если кто может, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
function Modal(modalEl, overlayEl) {
              this.modal = $(modalEl);
              this.overlay = $(overlayEl);
              this.wWidth = $(window).width();
              this.wHeight = $(window).height();
              this.dHeight = $(document).height();
        }
        Modal.prototype = {
              init: function(){
                this.bindHandlers();
              },
              bindHandlers: function(){
                var self = this;
                $('.modal-link').on('click', function(){
                      self.showModal();
                });
                $(window)
                      .resize(function() {
                        self.setWinSize($(this));
                        self.setModalPosition();
                     })
                       .scroll(function() {
                        self.setWinSize($(this));
                        self.setModalPosition();
                     });
                $('.close-button').click(function(){
                      self.hideModal();
                });
              },
              showModal: function(){
                this.overlay.fadeIn();
                this.modal.fadeIn();
                this.setModalPosition();
              },
              hideModal: function(){
                this.overlay.fadeOut();
                this.modal.fadeOut();
              },
              setModalPosition: function(){
                var modalHeight = this.modal.outerHeight(),
                        modalWidth = this.modal.outerWidth(),
                        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if(this.wHeight < modalHeight){
                      this.modal.css('top', scrollTop);
                } else {
                      this.modal.css('top', this.centerVertically(this.wHeight,modalHeight,scrollTop));
                }
                if(this.wWidth < modalWidth){
                      this.modal.css('left', 0);
                } else {
                      this.modal.css('left', this.centerHorizontally(this.wWidth,modalWidth));
                }
              },
              centerVertically: function(w, m, scroll){
                return ((w - m)/2 + scroll);
              },
              centerHorizontally: function(w, m){
                return (w - m)/2;
              },
              setWinSize:function(win){
                this.wWidth = win.width();
                this.wHeight = win.height();
              }
        }

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var modal = new Modal($('.modal-window'), $('.modal-overlay'));
        modal.init();
      });
```

---

```
<p class="modal-link">Открыть окно</p>
<div class="modal-overlay">
  <div class="modal-window">
    <p>содержимое</p>
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Принципиально использовать этот скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//в function Modal(modalEl, overlayEl) добавляете 1 параметр
function Modal(modalEl, overlayEl, modalOpener){
     this.modalOpener = $(modalOpener);
      ...
    //'.modal-link' заменяете на self.modalOpener
    $(self.modalOpener).on('click', function(){
        self.showModal();
    });
```

Comment: либо я вас не понял, либо вот http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvVgZe